# add transition time to onclick event react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add a transition time to an `onClick`-event.
The HomeCard element starts with a width of 600px and with the `onClick`-event of the button it goes to 100% width correctly.
The only problem is I am trying to delay the transition by 2 seconds and it's not working.
What would be the correct way to add a transition time in this case?

```
function App() {

const [cardWidth, setCardWidth] = useState("600px");

const setStyle = (cardWidth) => {
  setCardWidth(cardWidth);
}

const HomeCard = styled.div`
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 12px;
  width: ${cardWidth};
  transition: width 2s;
  height: 600px;
`

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <LogoWrapper/>
      <HomeCard>
        <Header>Text</Header>
        <CardText>Amet minim mollit non deserunt ullamco est sit aliqua dolor do amet sint</CardText>
        <Button onClick={() => setStyle("100%")}>See the animation</Button>
      </HomeCard>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Isn't [that](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#animations) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `transition-delay` CSS property to specify the duration to wait before starting the transition.

Or short `transition: <property> || <duration> || <timing-function> || <delay> [, ...];`

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) about CSS transitions

---

I suggest creating classes for your HomeCard element

```css
.home-card{
  width: 600px;
  transition: width 2s 2s;
}
.wide{
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 2s 2s;
}
```

and conditionally adding a `className` in React

```js
function App() {
  const [isWide, setIsWide] = useState(false);

  const toggleAnimation = () => {
    setIsWide(prev => !prev);
  }

  return (
    <div className={isWide ? "home-card wide" : "home-card"}>
        <button onClick={toggleAnimation}>See the animation</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```